# Spring Plug-in error on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I had installed Spring plug-in form Eclipse (Mars) MP.
Then it keep showing below error message page every time when I open the IDE:

> Plug-in "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted" was unable to instantiate class "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted.dashboard.WelcomeDashboard".

So I had removed the plug-in, however the error page still bother me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that is just some preference you can disable for the startup.
Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown